# How to detect empty ResultSet from MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How can I detect the empty result set sending from MySQL if there is no possible result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just check if [`ResultSet#next()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) returns true. E.g.

```
public boolean exist(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    boolean exist = false;

    try {
        connection = database.getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = MD5(?)");
        statement.setString(1, username);
        statement.setString(2, password);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        exist = resultSet.next();
    } finally {
        close(resultSet, statement, connection);
    }

    return exist;
}
```

which you can use like follows

```
if (userDAO.exist(username, password)) {
    // Proceed with login?
} else {
    // Show error?
}
```

Alternatively, you could also let it return a fullworhy `User` or `null` if there's none. E.g.

```
public User find(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    User user = null;

    try {
        connection = database.getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id, username, email, dateOfBirth FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = MD5(?)");
        statement.setString(1, username);
        statement.setString(2, password);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

        if (resultSet.next()) {
            user = new User(
                resultSet.getLong("id"),
                resultSet.getString("username"),
                resultSet.getString("email"),
                resultSet.getDate("dateOfBirth"));
        }
    } finally {
        close(resultSet, statement, connection);
    }

    return user;
}
```

with

```
User user = userDAO.find(username, password);

if (user != null) {
    // Proceed with login?
} else {
    // Show error?
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I hope that you've also received the hints as to how to use the JDBC stuff properly.