# JSF dynamic navigation is not functioning at all

Tags: java, jdbc, jsf-2

I have 3 jsf pages, first one for inserting data,username&password,then see if the data does exist in the database, after that navigate will play a role of redirecting to either welcome page in case of success or to wrong page if the data does not exist, here's the code :

ManagedBean code :

```
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    setters() & getters() 
    DBManager m = new DBManager(); 

  public String checkStatus() throws Exception{
    ResultSet rs = m.ExecuteQuery("select count(*) from user_authentication where user_name = 
   '"+userName+"' and user_password ='"+password+"' ");

   if(rs.next())  
    return "loggedIn";
         return "loggedOut";
}
```

DBManager.java code :

```
 public  Connection getConnection() {
    Connection cn = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/recruitment","root","123");
    }catch(Exception e){
    }        
    return cn;
  }


  public ResultSet ExecuteQuery(String sql)  {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement st = null;
    try {
        st = getConnection().createStatement();
        rs   = st.executeQuery(sql); 

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return rs;
 }
```

faces-config code :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  

/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
<managed-bean>
<managed-bean-name>obj</managed-bean-name>
<managed-bean-class>model.login</managed-bean-class>
<managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>
<from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
<display-name>welcome.xhtml</display-name>
<from-action>#{obj.checkStatus}</from-action>
<from-outcome>loggedIn</from-outcome>
<to-view-id>/welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
<navigation-case>
<display-name>wrong.xhtml</display-name> 
<from-action>#{obj.checkStatus}</from-action>
<from-outcome>loggedOut</from-outcome>
<to-view-id>/wrong.xhtml</to-view-id>    
</navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

here's the JSF login page code :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
 <h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
 </h:head>
 <h:body>
    Hello from Facelets
    <f:view>
    <h:form>
        user name   <h:inputText value="#{obj.userName}"/>
        password  <h:inputSecret value="#{obj.password}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="log-in" type="submit" action="#{obj.checkStatus()}"/>
    </h:form>
        </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The other 2 jsf pages tell if the operation done successfully. The problem is that the login page redirects to the welcome page regardless of the correctness of the data being inserted.

Answer (score 1):

A `SELECT count(*)` will **always** return a result. A count of `0` is also a valid result. In other words, your `rs.next()` always returns `true`. To fix your problem, you should rather select some column instead of a `count(*)`.

#### See also:

- [How to detect empty ResultSet from MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196605/how-to-detect-empty-resultset-from-mysql)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you've there a huge [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) hole and the code is leaking DB resources. Never concatenate user-controlled variables in a SQL string, but instead use `PreparedStatement`. Also always close DB resources like `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` in the `finally` block of the `try` where they've been opened.

#### See also:

- [CSRF, XSS and SQL Injection attack prevention in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-sql-injection-attacks-in-java-jsf)

Comment: I've done exactly as you told me, but now i got :`java.lang.StackOverflowError `

Comment: Well, something has run in an infinite loop. Hard to tell what exactly and how to solve it because you left out the stacktrace and I am not immediately able to beam over to you in person to see the stacktrace myself.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are really using JSF2 then all those entries (regarding managed-bean and naviagation-rule) in `faces-config.xml` are not required.

To redirect, append "?faces-redirect=true" to the action-method's return value:

```
return "loggedIn?faces-redirect=true";
```

Comment: I did not know, there are 2 versions of JSF, thanks a million .

Comment: While informative, this does not answer the concrete problem at all, nor does it explain how exactly it solves the navigation problem.

Comment: @BalusC: The way he put his title got me, didn't even read the whole question properly. Anyways thanks BalusC, there is a lot we can learn from you. +1.