# Java MYSQL check to see if a specific row exists

Tags: java, mysql

How do i check to see if a specific row exists in a table?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this with Java, or just in general?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect empty ResultSet from MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196605/how-to-detect-empty-resultset-from-mysql)

Comment: an example of how I would do this within java

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `SELECT` or `SELECT COUNT` statement. If they return anything, then, the row exists, else, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

This will cause the least network traffic:

```
select 1 from table where <conditions> limit 1
```